# automapper extension method

Tags: c#, automapper

Trying to make an automapper extension method so that I can replace (encrypt or decrypt) a string.

I'm hoping to do this with extension methods so that I can scan through all the properties dynamically rather than having to specify each one by hand

```
CreateMap<User, UserDto>().DecryptStrings();
CreateMap<UserDto, User>().EncryptStrings();

public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> DecryptStrings<TSource, TDestination>(this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> map)
{
    var sourceType = typeof(TSource);

    foreach (var prop in sourceType.GetProperties())
    {
        if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {        
            var name = (string)prop.GetValue(sourceType);
            var replacementValue = "test";
            map.ForMember(prop.Name, o => o.MapFrom(s => replacementValue));
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

Keep getting System.Reflection.TargetException: 'Object does not match target type'

Any help here much apprecaited

Comment: `GetValue`'s first argument must be an instance of the type. You're passing the type itself. You don't seem to use `name` for anything, so why not comment that line out?

Comment: Yeah that's going to be used, but haven't been able to populate it with the value of the property that i am after

Comment: See [this](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Value-transformers.html).

Comment: I've looked at this but that would only convert a string in one way, I need to be able to encrypt one way and decrypt the other way.